# Default Line Colors in LibreOffice Writer 5

Tags: libreoffice, 16.10

It seems like this should be pretty simple.

I want to change the default color of circles, ellipses, lines, etc.
When I draw a new line I don't want to have to choose a different style or toggle the color. It's too many clicks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was far simpler than I thought.

Simply change the color of the object you want to draw and it will automatically become the default for the rest of your session.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go .. do it like this

[image: Default ToolBar Image]

See this left icon

[image: Toolbar button]

Click this it will work